# React native - Arithmetic operations for values gathered using a form

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am very new to React Native and trying to finish the development work of one of very basic app. There are only two screens, a. Calculator and b. Result.
The Calculator screen has 2 input fields which can only accept a numeric value and upon hitting the result button an ideal case should be navigation push animation to Result screen and display of the result on the Result screen. Following is the code I have done so far, navigation is working fine but the only issue I can see is the result is not appearing as per my expectations. It seems to be I am failing to transfer numeric values to its relevant states.

*********** Calculator Screen ***********

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  ScrollView,
  KeyboardAvoidingView
} from 'react-native';
import Result from './Result';

export default class Calculator extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Calculator',
  };

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    cashOnHand: 0,
    cashInBank: 0,

    };
  };

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.form}>
      <Text>
        Please enter your values in respective fields.
      </Text>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior = 'position'>
      <TextInput placeholder = "Cash on hand"
      placeholderTextColor = "#635B53"
      keyboardType = 'numeric'
      onChangeText={cashOnHand => this.setState({cashOnHand})}
      style={styles.textFields}
      />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      <TextInput placeholder = "Cash in bank accounts"
      placeholderTextColor = "#635B53"
      keyboardType = 'numeric'
      onChange={cashInBank => this.setState({cashInBank})}
      style={styles.textFields}
      />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      <Button onPress={() => navigate('Result',{cashOnHand:this.state.cashOnHand,cashInBank:this.state.cashInBank})}
      title = 'Result'
      color = '#FFF'
      />
      </View>
      </ScrollView>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  form: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 37,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#0C66F3'
  },
  textFields: {
    height: 40,
    width: 300,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#A2C4E8',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    fontSize: 15,
    fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeue-Light',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
})
```

*********** Result Screen ***********

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import Calculator from './Calculator';

export default class Result extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Result',
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cashOnHand: this.props.navigation.state.params.cashOnHand,
  cashInBank: this.props.navigation.state.params.cashInBank,

      };
    };


  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View >
        <Text>
          Result Payable = {

              this.state.cashOnHand - this.state.cashInBank

          }
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, your not sending the variables cashOnHand and cashInBank to the 'Result' screen.Send it

```
onPress={() => navigate('Result',{cashOnHand:this.state.cashOnHand,cashInBank:this.state.cashInBank})}
```

Now in your 'Result' screen you have to read these values and set it to your state.

```
this.state = {
      cashOnHand: this.props.navigation.state.params.cashOnHand,
      cashInBank: this.props.navigation.state.params.cashInBank,
      };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Followed exactly how you mentioned and getting 'NaN' as a result of this operation. Please note that both fields have numeric values.

Comment: @SaqibAziz Initialize your `cashOnHand` and `cashInBank` with 0 instead of empty string in the constructor.

Comment: @TGMCians Thank you. I have now initialised both variables with 0 and still the result is appearing as 'NaN'

Comment: @SaqibAziz can you debug what you have in state ? I mean inside `onPress`

Comment: @TGMCians When I do not enter any numeric values in those fields, I get '0' on the result screen for some reason?

Comment: @SaqibAziz try this inside your Result screen...
`<Text>{parseInt(this.state.cashOnHand) - parseInt(this.state.cashInBank)`}</Text>

Comment: @RaviRaj I am afraid, the result still shows up 'NaN'

Comment: can you just console.log cashInBank and cashOnHand inside result screen render  and check the values

Comment: @RaviRaj Thank you for your suggestion. After console.log both cashOnHand and cashInBank on the 'Result' screen, it threw me error. Then I `{console.log(this.state.cashOnHand)}` and `{console.log(this.state.cashInBank)}` the 'Result' screen shows up empty spaces which makes me think that for some reason the state is not retaining the values from the TextInput fields in the 'Calculator' screen - Thoughts?

Comment: @RaviRaj Sorted. Thank you guys for all of your support. Actually I made a little typo in second TextInput instead of 'onChangeText' there was 'onChange'. Updating that fix the issue. Thank you again for all the tweaks and suggestions.